# filterring on IS NOT NULL using QSqlTableModel::setFilter(const QString &filter)

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, pyqt, pyside

If I'd like to filter on the [IS NOT NULL](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/is_not_null.php) condition using [QSqlTableModel::setFilter(const QString &filter)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter), what filter syntax should I pass to the method ?

Comment: Just wondering whether you read the documentation and understood it or not.  I think the docs are pretty straightforward about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter):

> The filter is a SQL WHERE clause without the keyword WHERE (for example, `name='Josephine'`).

So an appropriate filter with `IS NOT NULL` would resemble

```
mySqlTableModel.setFilter("id IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Thanks! I tired with your answer before , it didn’t work , but a later examination showed that it is because I saved an empty string “” instead of null in the database that caused the filter failed , worked after changed to mySqlTableModel.setFilter(‘id IS NOT “”’).

Comment: Ahaha, so the issue wasn't actually related with `is not null`. :P At least you've figured out and traced where the issue lay.